# Javascript support in etags

Tags: javascript, emacs, etag

I used etags to generate a TAGS file for emacs out of javascript source files.

Some functions are missing from the tag. Why ?

Does the javascript support include the following style

```
ZmZimletBase.prototype.doubleClicked =
function(canvas) {
    this.createPropertyEditor();
};
```

Hint : this style is also not supported by js-mode's js-find-symbole, which overrides the default M-. binding for find-tag.

Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [jsctags](https://github.com/mozilla/doctorjs). I have not used it so I am not sure if it has support for emacs as well as vim.